# Pandas: Assigning Float64 Series to Int32 Series fails with type error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, series

I am using Pandas 1.5.1 and am experiencing some strange type behavior with a conditional setitem:

```
>>> b = pd.Series([1.2, 2.2, 3.2], dtype="float64")
>>> a = pd.Series([1,2,3], dtype="int32")
>>> a[a < 2] = b
>>> a
0    1.2
1    2.0
2    3.0
dtype: float64
```

When both Series are using the numpy types, the assignment succeeds, however, if I change the numpy types to the Pandas extension types: pd.Float64Dtype() and pd.Int32Dtype(), and use the same data, the assignment fails:

```
>>> b = pd.Series([1.2, 2.2, 3.2], dtype="Float64")
>>> a = pd.Series([1,2,3], dtype="Int32")
>>> a[a < 2] = b

TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe' The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ca2_ps_env_3810\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1162, in __setitem__
    self._where(~key, value, inplace=True)
  File "C:\ca2_ps_env_3810\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 9733, in _where
    new_data = self._mgr.putmask(mask=cond, new=other, align=align)
  File "C:\ca2_ps_env_3810\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 407, in putmask
    return self.apply(
  File "C:\ca2_ps_env_3810\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 347, in apply
    applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
  File "C:\ca2_ps_env_3810\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 1517, in putmask
    values._putmask(mask, new)
  File "C:\ca2_ps_env_3810\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\base.py", line 1523, in _putmask
    self[mask] = val
  File "C:\ca2_ps_env_3810\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\masked.py", line 237, in __setitem__
    value, mask = self._coerce_to_array(value, dtype=self.dtype)
  File "C:\ca2_ps_env_3810\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\numeric.py", line 258, in _coerce_to_array
    values, mask, _, _ = _coerce_to_data_and_mask(
  File "C:\ca2_ps_env_3810\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\numeric.py", line 214, in _coerce_to_data_and_mask
    values = dtype_cls._safe_cast(values, dtype, copy=False)
  File "C:\ca2_ps_env_3810\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\integer.py", line 57, in _safe_cast
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: cannot safely cast non-equivalent object to int32
```

Is this error expected for this code? It's not clear to me why it considers the Float64Dtype() as an object data type when its a Pandas extension type, and why the same data using an extension type would cause the assignment to fail. If I use concat instead of setitem, it succeeds.

Comment: If you want to convert float to int, who knows you want to floor it or ceil it.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The difference between the working example and the failed example is the nullability of the dtype. The working example uses non-nullable numpy types. The failed example uses pandas nullable extension dtypes. Is it expected for their behavior to differ like this with the same data?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstand your question before. If you are not sure if this is intended, you can report a bug at https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas.